# Android - How to Block the Notification Manager When our App Runs

Tags: android

I want to know how I can disable or block the Notification Manager, while my application is running.

Meaning that the user cannot use the Notification Manager, ie a notification should not pop up.

Comment: if you don't want the status bar use a fullscreen mode

Answer (score 0):

You have to make it fullscreen, either:

Via manifest:

```
<activity ...
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
</activity>
```

Or via code:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: These all are the way to hide the Notification Manager
But i want to show the notification Manager But it should not be Deployable so please Help for that


the notification Manager Shoukd not be Dropped Down when our App Runs

Comment: So to be clear, you want to show the notification bar, but not the message that pops up?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set activity as full screen. If so, try this it might help you.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Source: http://www.androidsnippets.com/how-to-make-an-activity-fullscreen

Comment: These all are the way to hide the Notification Manager But i want to show the notification Manager But it should not be Deployable so please Help for that the notification Manager Shoukd not be Dropped Down when our App Runs

Answer (score 0):

By blocking the notification manager do you mean blocking notifications from your app when your app is in the foreground? I'm looking for something similar, and I think creating a service to manage notifications that are shown that can be messaged by activities when they start and stop may be what is needed.